# Running Android 5.0.1 x86 virtual device with host GPU disabled

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am working on automating screenshots capture for one of my apps.

Since I want to capture screenshots of some activities and widgets that differ according to the system locale, I start for each desired language a new Android virtual device (emulator) with the correct properties for setting the system locale. Then, specific user interactions are simulated with [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html).

My workflow is working as expected but I have an issue with screenshots capture. Indeed, using [UiDevice.takeScreenshot(File storePath)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#takeScreenshot(java.io.File)) or *screencap* on the emulator always creates an empty file.

It seems to be [a known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62284) with AVD running with Host GPU enabled (which is my case). The proposed workaround is to start the emulator with Host GPU disabled. Unfortunately, when I start the virtual device with Host GPU disabled, the emulated screen remains black.

I have taken a look at the output of the emulator with the `-verbose` option and `abd -e logcat` command ([emulator output](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lpellegr/b2ccfd0f062f55c56c3d/raw/e310abf1f4ac4f9651776a37068291aea9681fb0/avd_screenshots_output_emulator), [logcat output](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lpellegr/2edb9521a4f617369e57/raw/3aa286f5bb621b05a21b8081337448ab5dc7e24b/avd_screenshots_output_logcat)). In logcat ouput I have identified the following error but I cannot figure out the cause of it:

```
E/SurfaceFlinger(  929): hwcomposer module not found
E/SurfaceFlinger(  929): ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
```

Below is the command I use to start the emulator:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH emulator -avd screenshots -skin nexus_6 \
    -skindir $ANDROID_STUDIO_HOME/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources -no-audio \
    -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=en -verbose -qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm &
```

*I am running Fedora 21 with an Nvidia GPU.*

Does someone has succeeded to start an Android virtual device with a recent system image with Host GPU disabled? Any help or suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy cow! The problem I am facing is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76948). Workaround is to use a skin with lower screen resolution (e.g. nexus_4).