# Android studio version 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio version is updated to 2.0 and there when I create avd there is no option of "use host GPU" and I am getting an error of "disable use host GPU".
Help me.

Comment: Could be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373445/running-android-5-0-1-x86-virtual-device-with-host-gpu-disabled

Comment: Are you trying to run emulator of wearabe maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio v2.0, there is no option for disable "Use host GPU". On new AVD creation configuration dialog there option is "Emulated Performance --> Graphics".

In this option we have to select for used of computer's graphic card for emulator.

Please find image attachment for more information.

[image]